# How to obfuscate String in Android?

Tags: android, android-proguard

I want to obfuscate my api url.Can i use Proguard for this?If yes how do i do that?And how to add classes in Proguard configuration file to obfuscate the methods and variables​ present in the classes?

Comment: if you obfuscate you api url, your app won't be able to access the api

Comment: I find this article very useful https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/

Comment: If url is not possible than how do i obfuscate string.xml?

Answer (score 22):

You can now use a new gradle plugin + library to effectively obfuscate Strings in a class, Please check it here

https://github.com/MichaelRocks/paranoid

Also now there is a new plugin which can obfuscate resources also, please check it below

https://github.com/shwenzhang/AndResGuard

And help share and upvote this great information, so more developers can use it and thus more and more developers will contribute for further development of these plugins, and thus we can collectively improve these plugins and will give a nightmare for crackers.